# Ajax code is not working in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am using this code for my php MySql validation.

```
CheckID = document.getElementById('checkID_' + idCounter).value;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "checkval.php",
        data: { check : CheckID }
    }).done(function( data ) {
    if(data !== "success");
    {
    var  val = confirm(data);
            if (val === false) {
               return false;
            }
        }
 });
```

This code is not working, Script wrote after that also not working. No idea about check the bug. help me.....

this is my php script

```
<?php

    $check          = $_POST['check'];

        $host       = 'localhost';
        $database   = 'database';
        $username   = 'user';
        $password   = 'password';

    $dbc = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$database);
    $counter = count(checkArray);

        $checkno = $check;
        $sql = "select claimno from check_details where checkno = $checkno";
        $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$sql);
        $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if($rows != 0)
        {
                        $claim = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_BOTH);
            $claimno = $claim['claimno'];
            $str = "Check Number:$checkno is already applied for $claimno.Are you sure to contniue ???";
                        echo $str;
        }
                else
                {
                        echo "success";
                }   
?>
```

Comment: You cannot return values from inside an Ajax callback. That is like phoning for a pizza then eating it before it is delivered :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie +1 for example.. :)

Comment: It will also help if you show the surrounding code as your example is incomplete. Please :)

Comment: any suggestion for how can i call the php response

Comment: i just called one html text box thats all

Comment: Added example using promises below... Please say if you need more explanation of it.

Comment: What is the `false` being `returned` to in your code??? Show the code around *that* code.

Comment: from the php script i need to return false or claimno value, how can i get it from the ajax function

Comment: also help needed to edit the php script

Comment: `return false` there does nothing where you have it so is confusing. Your PHP just has to return a string of `success` or "something else" used to display a confirm message.

Comment: but in the case of check number existence i need to return the claimno.

Comment: Ah... now it makes a little more sense. You can return two values (the status and the checkid) in one JSON object and get the promise to return the `checkid` or cause `fail()` to fire. You really need to explain the overall aim with this type of question.

Comment: if i change my ajax like this with return value as false instead of success. is it possible?                          {  if (data !== "false");   }

Comment: You can decide to return false or a checkid as the payload, but why not return two properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write your function to return "a promise to return the boolean status value":

```
function getMeStatus(checkID){
    var def = $.Deferred();    // Create a deferred object
    $.ajax({                   // Make the ajax call
        type: "POST",
        url: "checkval.php",
        data: {check: CheckID}
    }).done(function (data) {
       if (data !== "success"); {
          var val = confirm(data);
          if (val === false) {
             // Status was false?
             def.resolve(false);
          }
          else {
             // Status was true?
             def.resolve(true);
          }
       }
       else {
          // Status was true?
          def.resolve(true);
       }
    }
    // return a promise to supply the boolean status value later
    return def.promise();
 });
```

and use it like:

```
CheckID = document.getElementById('checkID_' + idCounter).value;
getMeStatus(checkID).done(function(status){
    alert(status);  // Use the value here
});
```

### **Note:**

- *(Before everyone jumps on this,) this is not an anti-pattern if the return value has to be changed*
- This can be shortened a little, but the required logic from the question is not clear :)

Comment: Why not `def.reject()` + `def.resolve()` and `.done()`  + `.fail()` that seems much more readable to me?

Comment: @Daan: because the OP has not explain the purpose of the status. Once that becomes clear it can be shortened :)

Comment: @charlietfl: In this example there is no calling code, so all you are doing is moving the same code outside the function. I was explicit in naming the promise returned by this specific example. Feel free to post an alternative :)